# Dynamic permissions for model instances(objects) in deadbolt

Tags: permissions, playframework-2.0, authorization, user-permissions, deadbolt-2

we've got a system in which users are storing their creations(instances of models) in a database. Users can decide to share their creations with other users or groups of users.

My idea here is to associate the ID of a creation to a Permission in deadbolt and associate that Permission with a Subject.

What is the best way to do this? Should I even aim for deadbolt for this purpose or are there other frameworks/patterns to implement?

Comment: I've come a long way on this matter but not solved it yet. I know the concept for the solution though.

Comment: It seems no one has a solution for what we want to acheive, so we are going for a custom solution involving an ACL/RBAC hybrid.